# Extract double from file with words

Tags: c++, ifstream

I know that this might be an easy task and i found, reading the answer to other questions, that this code should do the trick

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


int main() {
  const char* filename = "integral_wh.out";
  std::ifstream inFile(filename);

  // Make sure the file stream is good
  if(!inFile) {
    cout << endl << "Failed to open file " << filename;
    return 1;
  }

double n;
string word;

while(inFile >> word >> n){

    cout << word;
    cout << n;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The text file I'm reading from is

```
Integral, Sample: Z/W + jets - ntp_Alpgen_Ztt.root      3.33645 +-    0.31588
Integral, Sample: Z/W + jets1 - ntp_Alpgen_Zmm.root      2.52853 +-    0.34243
Integral, Sample: Z/W + jets2 - ntp_Alpgen_Zee.root      7.97980 +-    0.70667
Integral, Sample: Z/W + jets3 - ntp_Wj_0.root      0.00000 +-    0.00000
Integral, Sample: Z/W + jets4 - ntp_Wj_1.root      0.67329 +-    0.48556
Integral, Sample: Z/W + jets5 - ntp_Wj_2.root      1.44122 +-    0.89388
```

when I run the program it can't read the double, it doesn't `cout` anything.
I tried also with

```
   while(inFile >> n){

        cout << n;
      }
```

and doesn't output anything. What i would like to obtain is the single numbers to use them for operations, maybe saving them into pairs, like

```
pair<double,double> alpgen = make_pair(3.33645,0.31588);
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a standard stream, the stream in operator (`operator>>`) uses a space to delimit tokens - in this case, your read operation will fail because it will read one string (`Integral,`), then the next token (`Sample:`) will attempt to be parsed into a double - which will fail.

You need to consume all the string tokens, then the double etc.

Comment: Oh that explains why it doesn't do what I'm expecting! I try to cycle over strings to consume the all before reading the double!

Answer (score 0):

How about reading the whole line, splitting into a vector on whitespace, and get the last and third to last items of the vector?

Comment: Yes this might work, I thought of the simplest thing to try and wondering why it isn't working.